# copy opengl main framebuffer to a fbo

Tags: opengl, fbo

I want to copy the opengl main framebuffer to a fbo, which attach two texture object. then I want transfer the color buffer and depth buffer to the two texture object. I use glbiltframebuffer,but the texure is black, what is right way? my code :

```
// Create the FBO
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_fbo);    
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);  

// Create textures
glGenTextures(1, &m_colorTexture);
glGenTextures(1, &m_depthTexture);

// color texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_colorTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, Width, Height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_colorTexture, 0); 

// depth texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_depthTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, Width, Height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_depthTexture, 0);

GLenum Status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (Status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    printf("error, status: 0x%x\n", Status);
    return false;
}

// restore default FBO
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);


    //copy the main framebuffer to FBO
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);  
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);  
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, Width, Height, 0, 0, Width, Height,  GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST); 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);       
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
GLenum error = glGetError();
```

`

Comment: How do you know that the copied data is black? Also, why are you mixing up extensions with core functionality? If you're using core FBOs, then you shouldn't have the `EXT` suffixes on anything.

Comment: I draw an object and bind the texture of FBO。when donot use EXT extension, also get black data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the code is right. Error occurred in other place, I am sorry. 
But I has been nagged by the bilt speed. I copy the main framebuffer to the fbo every frame. but it seems that the frame rate down a lot. can every one give some suggestion.